# siunitx not working in table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to use siunitx package to format tables, but it just doesn't seem to be working.  I am using texlive2012 installation under ubuntu 12.04.  A minimal "working" example would be:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
    \caption{Test}
 \begin{tabular}{S}
  {Test2} \\
  0.23 \\
  0.56
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When trying to compile this, it just gives me 3 errors with "undefined control sequence" - here an excerpt from the output:

```
l.14   {
        Test2} \\
! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;recently read&gt; ...gnore_spaces_execute_branches: 

l.15   0
        .23 \\
! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;recently read&gt; ...gnore_spaces_execute_branches: 

l.16   0
        .56
```

It would be great if someone could help me here ...

Thanks,
Juergen

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When I run your MWE on a system with MacTeX2011 with the latest versions of all packages installed, I don't get any error messages. When did you perform the most recent run of `tlmgr update --self -all` on your system?

Comment: You code also works with me (TL2012 + `siunitx 2012/07/22 v2.5g`). I believe a package update might help. `:)`

Comment: Indeed, that is an error due to mismatched package versions. You have an updated `siunitx` but older `l3kernel`/`l3packages`.

Comment: Well, that was the solution :-)  Thanks a lot!